# SQL how to append rows to columns?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, append, transpose

I have a table with many rows and two columns. So for instance, my table would look like this:

```
ID   Name

1     Bob

2    Jerry

3    Tom

4    John
```

Ultimately what I want though is for the table to look like this:

```
ID Name ID Name ID Name ID Name

1  Bob   2 Jerry 3 Tom 4 John
```

How would I do this in SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) to aggregate your rows in one column but like I said, it will be only one column. BTW, as I know, you can't have multiple columns with the same name :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ada08/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("ID" int, "Name" varchar2(5))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "Name")
         VALUES (1, 'Bob')
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "Name")
         VALUES (2, 'Jerry')
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "Name")
         VALUES (3, 'Tom')
    INTO Table1 ("ID", "Name")
         VALUES (4, 'John')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT listagg ("ID" || ' ' || "Name", ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) Result
FROM Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ada08/4/0)**:

```
|                     RESULT |
|----------------------------|
| 1 Bob 2 Jerry 3 Tom 4 John |
```